# Zoom Out / Zoom In "Activity" with two fingers

Tags: android, android-layout

What I want is to zoom in / out the activity with two fingers. I'm not saying 'Picture', I'm saying 'Activity'. Because I have both Edittext, Textview, and Checkbox in my Activty. And there are many of them. I couldn't find information on this. Can you help me? Thanks..

Comment: try https://github.com/alexvasilkov/GestureViews. just wrap your layout inside a GestureView.

Answer (score 1):

You can implement [this library](https://github.com/Polidea/android-zoom-view/blob/master/src/pl/polidea/view/ZoomView.java). To use it, import it or simplier create a ZoomView file in your project. It's a FrameLayout so you just need to put ZoomLayout as the mother view of your layout.